# Android Studio with databasehelper - no data saves! Deadline in 3 hours

Tags: java, database, android-studio

Something is wrong and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Please help!
I want to add, update, delete and search data with a databasehelper in Android Studio and in java.
The application is going to work like an activityList sort off, a veeery poor one. But the concept is to work with a databasehelper.

This is my MainActivity:

```java
package com.example.appdatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper  db;
    EditText        activity,
                    day,
                    time;
    Button          createNewActivity,
                    getAllActivities,
                    deleteActivity,
                    updateActivity,
                    searchActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        activity            = findViewById(R.id.activity);
        day                 = findViewById(R.id.day);
        time                = findViewById(R.id.time);
        createNewActivity   = findViewById(R.id.createNewActivity);
        getAllActivities    = findViewById(R.id.getAllActivities);
        deleteActivity      = findViewById(R.id.deleteActivity);
        updateActivity      = findViewById(R.id.updateActivity);
        searchActivity      = findViewById(R.id.searchActivity);

        createNewActivity();
        getAllActivities();
        deleteActivity();
        updateActivity();
        searchActivity();
    }

    public void createNewActivity() {
        createNewActivity.setOnClickListener (view -> {
            boolean create = db.createNewActivity(activity.getText().toString(), day.getText().toString(), time.getText().toString());
            if  (create == true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Aktivitet tillagd.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fel! Aktivitet är inte tillagd.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            activity.setText("");
            day.setText("");
            time.setText("");
        });
    }

    public void getAllActivities() {
        getAllActivities.setOnClickListener (view -> {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllActivities();
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                showMessage("ActivityList: ", "Inga aktiviteter!");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("Aktivitet: " + cursor.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Dag: " + cursor.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Dag: " + cursor.getString(2) + "\n" + "\n");
            }
            showMessage("ActivityList: ", buffer.toString());

        });
    }

    public void deleteActivity() {
        deleteActivity.setOnClickListener (view -> {
            Integer delete = db.deleteActivity(activity.getText().toString());
            if (delete > 0)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Aktivitet är borttagen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fel! Aktivitet är inte borttagen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            activity.setText("");
            day.setText("");
            time.setText("");
        });
    }

    public void updateActivity() {
        updateActivity.setOnClickListener (view -> {
            boolean update = db.updateActivity(activity.getText().toString(), day.getText().toString(), time.getText().toString());
            if (update == true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Aktivitet är uppdaterad.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fel! Aktivitet är inte uppdaterad.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            activity.setText("");
            day.setText("");
            time.setText("");
        });
    }

    public void searchActivity() {
        searchActivity.setOnClickListener (view -> {
            if (activity.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ange aktivitet. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String active = activity.getText().toString();
            Cursor cursor = db.searchActivity(active);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                activity.setText(cursor.getString(0));
                day.setText(cursor.getString(1));
                time.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finns ingen sådan aktivitet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        build.setCancelable(true);
        build.setTitle(title);
        build.setMessage(message);
        build.show();
    }
}
```

And this is the DatabaseHelper:

```java
package com.example.appdatabase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "ActivityPlan_table";
    private static final String COLUMN_ACTIVITY = "activity";
    private static final String COLUMN_DAY = "day";
    private static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (activity INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_DAY + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_TIME + " TEXT) ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean createNewActivity (String activity, String day, String time) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ACTIVITY, activity);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_DAY, day);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME, time);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getAllActivities() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public boolean updateActivity (String activity, String day, String time) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ACTIVITY, activity);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_DAY, day);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME, time);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "activity = ?", new String[] {activity});
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteActivity (String activity) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "activity = ?", new String[]{activity});
    }

    public Cursor searchActivity (String activity) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ACTIVITY + "='" + activity + "'", null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you never close the database and so also never commit the changes.
Try adding `db.close()` at the end of every method using

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
```

or, if you don't want to close them use `db.releaseReference()`, this should work too (i just saw it and didn't test it, so close() is the saver and also a better way, as you should close your database connection if you don't need it anymore

datatype mismatch normally means that you are trying to insert a value with the wrong data type. Meaning that a value ? is not of the same type as day|time or activity.
If you save them as a string, note that you have to put '' around the value.

Your closing needs to be placed at the end of the methods using `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` for example:

```
public boolean updateActivity (String activity, String day, String time) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ACTIVITY, activity);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_DAY, day);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME, time);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "activity = ?", new String[] {activity});
        db.close(); // place your closing here
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to put in some closings, but I can't figure out where to put them. They just become unreachable.
In the logcat it says: "[INSERT INTO ActivityPlan_table(day,time,activity) VALUES (?,?,?)] datatype mismatch". But I have used String everywhere...

Comment: Fixed it! But it still doesn't work as it should. I think it is something I'm thinking wrong regarding the datatype.

Comment: What's the problem? Does another error occurs, or can't you read the date, or something similar?